# What does "Pseudo object oriented language" mean?

Tags: oop

What is meant by the term "pseudo object oriented language" ? i have found article that says its harmful but what is meant by it ? I have searched for the term and it doesn't say much.

Comment: It is not a common term. Probably you have to check the definition from the article.

Comment: I would guess that it means that some implementation was done in a language that does not directly support object-oriented programming, but object-oriented patterns are used.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the article, please?

Comment: @DoeJohnson found it on a python tutorial of oop, can't find the link anymore, sorry.

Comment: @rumman0786 Without having a look at that article this question cannot be solved properly. Please search one more time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to this: http://www.idinews.com/westfall.pdf

Basically it isn't saying that the language is "pseudo oo", he is saying that the way it is being used is.

Just throwing objects into things and claiming that it makes it Object Oriented is wrong and teaches people bad habits. The example there just wraps a procedural methodology in an object, rather than truly being object oriented.